# How to see source code of jar attached through maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I am working on maven project in eclipse and I have some 7-10 jar files. I have added dependency of those jar files in my POM file. But when I click any function which is part of libraries, my eclipse complains that no source code found. All jar files are successfully downloaded in my local maven repository. I am struggling to attach source code. I have already tried downloading sources and Javadoc under maven but it is still not working.

Comment: What kind of project is it? (Ex : Dynamic Web, JPA, EAR) ?

Comment: I am creating a RESTful API using CXF

Comment: Do ou have maven dependencies on your build path (Do you see it in eclipse?)

Comment: Yes I do have. When I click function I get following error The Jar file C:\users\au45879\.m2\repository\emc\emc-dfs-rt\emc-dfs-rt\emc-dfs-rt.jar has no source attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool to decompile .jar files, for example [this](http://jd.benow.ca).

Other option is use the Jetbrains IntelliJ IDE that includes a potent decompiler right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have Maven Dependencies on your build path

[image]

Comment: Yes I do have. When I click function I get following error The Jar file C:\users\au45879\.m2\repository\emc\emc-dfs-rt\emc-dfs-rt\emc-dfs-rt.jar has no source attachment.

Comment: Go to this folder C:\users\au45879\.m2\repository\emc\emc-dfs-rt\emc-dfs-rt\ - do you em‌​c-dfs-rt.jar there?

Comment: Ok, delete it and then ask maven to update project, it will download file again to local repo. Then check if it works.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use more popular [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) IDE rather than eclipse, you can view jar source code easily.

Comment: yeah but only thing is not open source:)

Comment: This is not a solution of OP's problem.